# Ambassador responds with "no healthy upstream"

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, ambassador

I have a simple k3s cluster with the Ambassador ingress controller installed as per the [docs](https://www.getambassador.io/yaml/ambassador/ambassador-rbac.yaml)

When I try to access the service through my browser, I just get a "no healthy upstream" message.

These are my configs:

```
$ kubectl describe svc web-test-service
Name:              web-test-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=web-test
Annotations:       Selector:  app=web-test
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.43.109.123
Port:              <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.1.19:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

```
$ kubectl describe svc ambassador
Name:                     ambassador
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=ambassador-service
Annotations:              Selector:  service=ambassador
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.43.12.194
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.136.64.114
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30005/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.0.10:8080,10.42.1.28:8080,10.42.1.29:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     30928
Events:                   <none>
```

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-test-5594bffd47-8pzdk   1/1     Running   0          175m
svclb-ambassador-p5rr7      1/1     Running   0          24m
svclb-ambassador-k4j52      1/1     Running   0          24m
ambassador-58b444b8-tqjkk   1/1     Running   0          24m
ambassador-58b444b8-b9x7v   1/1     Running   0          24m
ambassador-58b444b8-wfclj   1/1     Running   0          24m
```

I've checked the service logs and the application is up and running and listening on port 8080.

Comment: are your pods labelled "app=web-test"?